# Adding a class which extends JLabel into a panel with gridlayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a cinema hall with Swing. So for this purpose I've created a class `Seat` which extends `JLabel`:

```
public class Seat extends JLabel{

public boolean isVip() {
    return vip;
}

public boolean isHandicap() {
    return handicap;
}

public boolean isOccupato() {
    return occupato;
}

public void setVip(boolean vip) {
    this.vip = vip;
}

public void setHandicap(boolean handicap) {
    this.handicap = handicap;
}

public void setOccupato(boolean occupato) {
    this.occupato = occupato;
}
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean vip;
private boolean handicap;
private boolean occupato;


public Seat(int x, int y, ImageIcon img) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.setIcon(img);
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}
}
```

And I want to use this class to draw the seats in a hall, and with an action listener change seats color when they are clicked.

But when I try to add my seats in a panel with `GridLayout`, my seats are shown one over the other.

```
public class PanelAddHall extends JPanel {

private int x=5;
private int y=5;
private ArrayList<Seat> seats = null;

public PanelAddHall(Controller_Gestore controller, final JLabel outputGrafico) {
    seats = new ArrayList<>();
    this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,30));
    JPanel nord = new JPanel();
    JPanel sud = new JPanel(new GridLayout(x,y,0,5));
    JPanel west = new JPanel();
    nord.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    sud.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    west.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    ImageIcon seat_icon = new ImageIcon("immagini/poltrone/seat_disponibile.png");
    ImageIcon screen_icon = new ImageIcon("immagini/poltrone/screen.png");

    JLabel screen = new JLabel(screen_icon);
    nord.add(screen);
    for(int i = 0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++){
            seats.add(new Seat(i,j,seat_icon));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<x*y ; i++) {

        sud.add(seats.get(i));
    }

    this.add(nord, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(sud, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);



}
```

[image: The result is this..]

Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're overriding `JComponent` methods `getX` and `getY` in your class `Seat`.

If you need that coordinates for reservation purposes change those methods names.

I've created this simple GUI to test your class (using a different image) and it works as intended if those two methods are commented.

```
  import java.awt.GridLayout;

  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

  public class SimpleFrameTest2 extends JFrame {

      public SimpleFrameTest2() {

           setSize(500, 500);
           setTitle("Test");
           setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           setResizable(true);

           initComponents();

           setVisible(true);

       }

       private void initComponents() {

           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 0, 5));

           ImageIcon seat_icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Pictures\\referencias\\seating-chart.png");

           for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                //panel.add(new JLabel("" + i, seat_icon, JLabel.CENTER));
                panel.add(new Seat(i, i, seat_icon));
            }

            add(panel);

       }


       public static void main(String args[]){

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     new SimpleFrameTest2();
                 }
            });   

        }  

     }
```

[image]

EDITED:
This is the image that I've used http://www.marcuscenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/seating-chart.png

Comment: Hi Rubio, i'have a favor to ask you, can you give me the .png file of seats which you have used? or tell me where you found them.

Comment: @YatD3siB0y Sure. No problem. http://www.marcuscenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/seating-chart.png Be so kind to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding the JComponent getX() getY() methods which prevent the JPanel to layout the Labels properly